# "'NoneType' object has no attribute ..." when object checked not to be None?

Tags: python

How is possible that in Python if they first check if some object is not None (`if popResult:`) they use that object in `else` branch to get its Attribute `messages` list?
I am not an expert for Python but I am using some already very reliable GitHub script -
https://github.com/NavicoOS/ac2git/

```
def TryPop(self, streamName, transaction):
    logger.debug("**** entered TryPop method *******")
    for i in range(0, 2):
        popResult = accurev.pop(verSpec=streamName, location=self.gitRepo.path,elementList='.')
        if popResult:
            break
        else:
            logger.error("accurev pop failed:")
            for message in popResult.messages:
                if message.error is not None and message.error:
                    logger.error("  {0}".format(message.text))
                else:
                    logger.info("  {0}".format(message.text))
    
    return popResult
```

With this script I got the following error:

```
  File "/home/ac2git/ac2git.py", line 965, in TryPop
    for message in popResult.messages:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'messages'
```

Again - as this is one of the basic methods for this project, I really doubt that developers made such a beginner's mistake, because this project has been used in many years for migrating from some other SCM to Git, but on the other hand I really cannot see how they could use object (`popResult`) to retrieve its attribute if that object is `None`? Is it possible to put something like this in else branch?

Could you please provide me guidance for this or correction of the code if needed?

Comment: If an object provides a `__bool__` method it is called to determine if an "if" condition consisting of this object should be true or false. So "else" part may be triggered if the object is e. g. in an error state but not necessarily "None".

Comment: I'm guessing that they expect `popResult` to be "false-y" object other than `None` when popping fails. (Not handling `None`s seems to be a recurring pattern in that project.)

Comment: Indeed the obj.Pop class has a dedicated `__bool__` function. you can find it [here](https://github.com/NavicoOS/ac2git/blob/c11e9793eec948476c59d1d1a1d4a9d49e7788ac/accurev.py#L1365)

Comment: try to understand when the bool function returns false. After that try to understand how you can get false and have no message attribute. Hint look into the Pop class of the project.

Comment: You found an special edge case which seems to be overlooked by the devs! Good job, your pull request will help to make it better!

Comment: @Doluk This has nothing to do with `__bool__`. `accurev.pop` returns `None`... Doing `if None:` will always be falsey...

Comment: I didn't understand if this is your code or part of the repo's code, but I'm pretty sure that `if message.error is not None and message.error:` is just the same as `if message.error:`

Comment: @Tomerikoo correct. I thought, that the code is part of the project and therefore the code works in general, and the edge case is only the problem. And neglected the error. my bad, thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have explicitly check if `popResult` is `None` before trying to access its members:

```py
def tryPop(self, streamName, transaction):
    logger.debug("**** entered TryPop method *******")
    for i in range(0, 2):
        popResult = accurev.pop(verSpec=streamName, location=self.gitRepo.path,elementList='.')
        if popResult is None:
            print("popResult is None !")
            continue
        elif popResult:
            break
        else:
            logger.error("accurev pop failed:")
            for message in popResult.messages:
                if message.error is not None and message.error:
                    logger.error("  {0}".format(message.text))
                else:
                    logger.info("  {0}".format(message.text))
    
    return popResult
```

But actually `popResult` being None is just a symptom of some other error you made and the above does not cure the original cause which I'm unsure of - try using an absolute, full path for `elementList`.

Comment: This prevents the error, but imo this is an unhandled special case of the project. so the fix should be more located on their side

Comment: agree with @Doluk, but for know although it does not resolve the root cause we can use this as temp workaroud. Thanks both of you for assistance

Comment: I would personally put the `if popResult is None:` inside the `else` - `if popResult: break` is for when the pop was successful and the loop terminates. The `else` is for anything else...